# Ignore filters executing on requests made to specific endpoints

Tags: java, spring

I have the following config method for my `WebSecurityConfig` that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(
            new JWTAuthenticationFilter(userDetailsServiceBean()),
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

`JWTAuthenticationFilter` actually filters requests received on all endpoints, and checks if they have the correct JWT authentication token in their headers.

I don't expect this filter to execute on requests made to the `/login` endpoint ! Is there a way to ignore the filter for special endpoints ? (here `/login` and `/signup`).

Is there any good reason to keep this filter executing on requests made to all endpoints including `login` and `signup` ?

Comment: you can do it with `http.antMatcher([some pattern])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try adding the following

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()                
            .antMatchers("/login**", "/signup**");
}
```

Comment: Is it a good practice to ignore `permitAll` endpoints from being authenticated with filters ?

Comment: Well, Not all. But it makes more sense to ignore login and signup because whenever these Endpoints are accessed most of the time there will be no User authenticated.

Comment: btw, why did you put `/login**` and not `login` ?

Comment: `**` at the end will support Query Strings. If you don't put it. `/login` will be ignored but `/login?success=false` will not.

Comment: By adding `.ignoring` (what you suggested) should I take those endpoints out of the `configure` method that I had and you can see in the question ?